# Gradle: What is the difference between providedCompile and providedRuntime

Tags: gradle

Gradle doc says:

> "The War plugin adds two dependency configurations: providedCompile
>   and providedRuntime. Those configurations have the same scope as the
>   respective compile and runtime configurations, except that they are
>   not added to the WAR archive."

What is the difference between providedCompile and providedRuntime?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`providedCompile` is visible when classes in your project are compiled (`compile` extends `providedCompile`). `providedRuntime` is extended by `runtime` and thus also by `testRuntime` but it is not part of compilation classpath.

Comment: So, the artifact mentioned as `providedRuntime` will not be resolved while building?